# NameError: name 'f' is not defined

Tags: python

I am working to create a quiz on Python with different difficulty levels. I am trying to use functions so I can keep calling the most frequent part of the code, appending the questions into a list from an external text file.

However, I am running into a problem. When attempting to call my function I get the error:

```
NameError: name 'f' is not defined
```

I've tried everything I can think of but if anyone could provide any help, it would be greatly appreciated!

Here is the function:

```
def quiz(f):
    f = open("quiz.txt", "r").read().split('\n')
    for line in f:
        f.append(questions)
    f.close()
quiz(f)
print(questions)
```

The `print(questions)` bit is just a way for me to check if the lines have appended to the list.

Comment: Please fix the syntax in your sample code so it runs (well, generates the specific error you're asking out instead of a SyntaxError) when copy-and-pasted. See the [mcve] definition.

Comment: Fix your indentation. Why are you passing `f` to the function anyway?

Comment: Also, it's quite unhelpful that you're defining `f` more than once -- in one place it's a parameter name, in another it's a local (or maybe module-scoped, depending on context and indentation) variable.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy syntax fixed

Comment: with the syntax fixed, the issue is pretty obvious. There *isn't* any `f` defined outside the function, and yet you're trying to pass it such a variable despite said variable's nonexistence.

Comment: You're getting confused between `f` as a function argument, `f` as a local variable inside the function and `f` as a (nonexistent) global variable. Calling `quiz(f)` from the main body would mean you've already defined some variable `f` and you're passing it **into** the function. But currently your `quiz()` function ignores its argument `f`, it overrides it with `f = open("quiz.txt"...` So either change `quiz()` to need take any arguments : `def quiz()`, or else define your filename `f` as a global variable in main. Your choice.

Answer (score 3):

When your code hits the line `quiz(f)`, no `f` has been defined.

At that point in your code, only one thing has happened -- a function name `quiz` has been defined.  That's the only identifier you can refer to at that point in your code.

You have declared function `quiz` to accept a parameter, but it makes no use of that parameter.  The correct definition would be `def quiz()`.

Comment: Now it just says 'AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'close''

Comment: Oh, there are a lot more problems.  In that case, you're trying to call `.close()` on the variable `f`, probably thinking `f` is a file.  But it's not, it's the result of reading the file and splitting it on the newline character -- in other words, it's a list of strings.  A list has no `close()` method.

Comment: Would there be any fix?

Comment: Yes, several different possibilities.  You could keep a reference to f as the file  `f = open('quiz.txt', 'r')` and a separate reference in another variable to the data you read from it.  But the most correct way is using the Python `with` keyword: `with open('quiz.txt', 'r') as f:` which eliminates the need to close the file at all.